# Hidden form inputs are causing PHP Notice: Undefined variable:

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, error-handling

When users submit a form leaving some of it's fields empty, to populate the associated empty fields of database with predefined data the following codes first check if the users are leaving the form's fields empty and then insert the predefined data in to the respective fields `issuing_date` `reference_details` and `name` of database through hidden form inputs.

```
if ((isset($_POST["submit_form"])) && ($_POST["submit_form] == "Submit")) { 

$issue_date = $_POST['DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'];

$reference = "Not Available";
if(isset($_POST['reference_details']) && !empty($_POST['reference_details'])){  
$reference = $_POST['reference_details'];
}

$drawer_name = "Not Available";
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){  
$drawer_name = $_POST['name'];
}

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO table (issuing_date, reference_details, name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",

GetSQLValueString(trim($issue_date), "date"),
GetSQLValueString(trim($reference), "text"),
GetSQLValueString(trim($drawer_name), "text"));

and do more.......
```

---

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_form" id="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="hidden" name="issuing_date" value="<?php echo "$issue_date"; ?>" />---->Line110
<input type="hidden" name="reference_details" value="<?php echo "$reference"; ?>" />---->Line111
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo "$drawer_name"; ?>" />---->Line112
```

When `error_log` is active, the `form page` produces the following example of notice in the `error_log` whenever it is launched in the web browser.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: issuing_date in /home/user/public_html/dir/subdir/test.php on line 110
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: reference_details in /home/user/public_html/dir/subdir/test.php on line 111
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: name in /home/user/public_html/dir/subdir/test.php on line 112
```

What's going wrong here? Are the hidden inputs of the form defined incorrectly?

Any idea?

Comment: Which lines are 110-112? 
EDIT: My mistake I see it now.

Comment: Is `$issue_date` actually being set before trying to use it in the hidden inputs?

Comment: @PrimitiveType I think I screwed up, OP mentioned errors in their form so it's probably the hidden fields...

Comment: @SilentPond You should probably provide more code because these snippets only cause speculation as to where your are defining and using these variables...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `$issue_date = $_POST['DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'];` here the database field `issuing_date` has the value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` predefined.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus , do you give me a hint about what further codes make my question more precise? The form is a traditional one that was correctly coded except the hidden inputs which are causing the notice.

Comment: does GetSQLValueString return NULL when the value of $issue_date is == ""?  This may cause echo to spit out that error.  Variables set to null always seem problematic if not handled with care.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus , I added further details.

Comment: @dboals all the variables are set to `not null`

Comment: Is this a scoping issue.  We can't see all the {} blocks you have, but could this be that the $issue_date in one scope is not the same as the $issue_date in another scope.  I have run into unexpected scoping issues with php before.  To test this try adding $issue_date="" at the top of the file outside of any {} blocks and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: @dboals I get the notice on entrance to the page before any form action.

Comment: so the error is on the form page with out a "submit"? This means that none of the code within the first code block above is executed based on the "if" statement ---> Add '$issue_date =""; $reference_details=""; $name="";  ' at the top of your test.php file and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @dboals, I don't try your code yet but I'm sure this is the correct solution as all the database fields are set to `not null`. Thus, empty variables produce the notice. Once I set the values of variables to null, in case there isn't any available there, the problem shall go away. There wouldn't be any undefined variable notice there if the database fields were set to `null`. I guess this also can be done this way `$_post['issue_date'] = '';` or by checking the viariable declaration status like, `$issue_date = isset($_POST['issuing_date']) ? $_POST['issuing_date'] : '';` too. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon initial loading of your form you have not posted any data to it so it never enters this code block:

**1st load - visiting the page**

```
if ((isset($_POST["submit_form"])) && ($_POST["submit_form"] == "Submit")) { // Data received from your submit button is not available because the form was not submitted

    // We never make it here so $issue_date is not available when you need it

    $issue_date = $_POST['DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'];

    // everything else

}
```

**2nd load - submitting the form to itself**

```
if ((isset($_POST["submit_form"])) && ($_POST["submit_form"] == "Submit")) { // Data received from your submit button is available so we enter this block of code

    // We made it here so $issue_date is available later on

    $issue_date = $_POST['DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'];

    // everything else

}
```

### You have three choices:

**1 - turn off error reporting**

^ This is the easiest solution and should always be done in a Production environment or a public-facing website

At the very beginning of your file do this:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

**2 - use isset() to figure out if the variable has been declared**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_form" id="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="hidden" name="issuing_date" value="<?php echo (isset($issue_date) ? $issue_date : ''); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="reference_details" value="<?php echo (isset($reference) ? $reference: ''); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo (isset($drawer_name) ? $drawer_name: ''); ?>" />
```

**3 - declare your variables before the if(){} block**

```
$issue_date = NULL;
$reference = NULL;
$drawer_name = NULL;

if ((isset($_POST["submit_form"])) && ($_POST["submit_form"] == "Submit")) {

    $issue_date = $_POST['DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'];

    // everything else
}
```

Comment: thanks. The form works well when error reporting is off but I was trying to figure out the root of a problem that prevents the cleanliness of the code or keeps the code away from being clean. I actually need the issue date on 2nd load. However, your answer is something I expected.

Comment: your 2nd solution is something I expected.

Answer (score 0):

did you set the variable before?

```
$variable = $_POST['NAME VALUE'];
```

for example if the column in the DB is **test**

you have to set

```
$variablename = $_POST['test'];
```

of course you even have to run the query

Comment: if you read my question carefully, you may realize that, defining a post variable isn't related to my problem. I receive this notice  whenever I launch the page in the browser before any form action. It's really very strange.